# How to assign classes in an array randomly to an element created in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, classname, createelement

I'm using a for loop to create many divs, assign a class name, and append to a parent div. What I'm having difficulty with is additionally  including more classes—randomly—from an array. Below is a snippet.

```
let classesArray = ['slowest', 'slow', 'medium', 'fast', 'fastest'];
let randomClass = classesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * classesArray.length)];

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  const test = document.createElement('div');
  test.className = 'speed ' + randomClass;
  document.getElementById('div-parent').appendChild(test);
}
```

I'm able to create the child divs with the class of 'speed' and a random class is being included also, but I'm getting that same random class on all the divs.

I'm hoping it would look something like this

```
<div id="div-parent">
  <div class="speed fast"></div>
  <div class="speed slow"></div>
  <div class="speed medium"></div>
  ...
```

But it ends up something like this

```
<div id="div-parent">
  <div class="speed fast"></div>
  <div class="speed fast"></div>
  <div class="speed fast"></div>
  ...
```

Is it possible to randomly select a class from the array and not be repeated on all of the child divs?

Comment: Move the random statement inside the loop

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong...
because `let randomClass = classesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * classesArray.length)];` is exist in outside loop.

move inner loop~

```
let classesArray = ['slowest', 'slow', 'medium', 'fast', 'fastest'];


for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * classesArray.length));
  const randomClass = classesArray[randomIndex];

  const test = document.createElement('div');
  test.className = 'speed ' + randomClass;
  document.getElementById('div-parent').appendChild(test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

being `randomClass` is created outside of the loop, it has the same value in each iteartion of the loop.

Declare `randomClass` inside the loop so that it can take the newly generated random class in each iteration:

```js
let classesArray = ['slowest', 'slow', 'medium', 'fast', 'fastest'];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let randomClass = classesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * classesArray.length)];
  const test = document.createElement('div');
  test.className = 'speed ' + randomClass;
  document.getElementById('div-parent').appendChild(test);
}

console.log(document.getElementById('div-parent').innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="div-parent"></div>
```

Comment: Really worth answering?